# Evaluate $\int_{+\gamma} \frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)}{1+iz} \, dz$. The antiderivative of $f(z)$ is not differentiable at a point on the contour

Tags: complex-analysis

We need to compute this integral $\int_{+\gamma} \frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)}{1+iz} \, dz$ with the contour from $-1$ to $1$ then from $1$ to $2+i$. Can we do it in this way

$$\int_{+\gamma} \frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)}{1+iz}\,dz = \int_{+\gamma} \operatorname{Log}(1+iz) \, d \operatorname{Log}(1+iz) = \frac{-i}{2} [\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)]^2 \big|_{-1}^{2+i}?$$

On the second equality, I assumed we use the branch $-\pi \le \arg(1+iz) < 2\pi$. Can I do that? The $\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)$ is not holomorphic on the ray $\{i\ge 1\}$ and the point $0$ is on the contour, which make me confused.

Comment: No need to be confused. The integrand is holomorphic on the path of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of demonstration, I will show how to integrate
$$I:=\int^1_{-1}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+iz)}{1+iz}$$ where the path of integration is a straight line.

First, we will apply a substitution $u=iz$ on the integral. Substitutions aren’t always valid for complex integrals, but linear substitutions are.

Thus,
$$I=\int^i_{-i}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+u)}{1+u}(-i du)$$

The integrand has a branch point at $-1$, and the branch cut extends on the ray $u<-1$.

Secondly, due to
$$\frac{d}{dz}\ln(z)=\frac1z$$ for **any** branch cut of $\ln$, we have $$d(\operatorname{Log(1+u)})=\frac{1}{1+u}du$$

Thus, as you expected,
$$I=-i\int^{u=i}_{u=-i}\operatorname{Log}(1+u)~d(\operatorname{Log}(1+u))=-\frac i2\cdot\operatorname{Log}^2(1+u)\bigg\vert^i_{-i}=\frac{\pi\ln 2}4$$

---

Moreover, integration along your path is the same as directly integrating from $-1$ to $2+i$ along a straight line. You can justify it by Cauchy’s integral theorem.